# Can OpenSearch dashboard shown in my web app

Tags: opensearch-dashboards

I was working with OpenSearch dashboard where I could able to generate some visualizations and show up in the dashboard.

I found an option to export dashboard as the "Embedded code" or "Permalinks".

My interest is if I could pull the that code from my web app to show dashboard visuals/charts in my application.

Is it possible to pull the charts/visuals using REST API or other means?